# Two active-low switches, delay between the two

Tags: delay, active-low

I have two active low outputs, each with a 12V potential when opened.  I'd like to create a circuit where, after the a switch to the first input is grounded, there is a small delay (>= 500ms) and then the second output is grounded.

I feel like this should be possible with an RC circuit and a transistor, but my design skills are severely limited.  I have already tried such a circuit, wired as shown: [image: transistor circuit with RC time delay]

Comment: (1) your switch will short the 12v  (2) other than shorting your supply, wouldn't output 1 just stay at 12V the whole time?  (3) there would have to be a resistor between 12V and output 1 (4) this still wouldn't fix output 2, see Andy's answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your circuit is that it would need an extra resistor: -

[image]

If you can't fit that resistor then you need to think of a different way.